# php : time intevals compare find out intersection

Tags: php

```
$times=[
0=>'08:00-09:00'
1=>'09:20-13:00'
2=>'14:00-18:00'
3=>'06:00-20:00'
];
```

now I have many time intevals in an array ,and don't know how many there is ,give a new time ,I want to find out the cross times ,for example ,give me 07:00-10:00，then $time[0],time[1],time[3] intersect with the given time .

***my solution is:-*** use `foreach()` to compare the begin and end of each item

but I think there is a better solution for this . because we can assume the time interval is coordinate on the x axis , please help me ,thank you .

Comment: `for example ,give me 07:00-10:00，then $time[0],time[1],time[3] intersect with the given time .` => what is the logic behind this?

Comment: _“but I think there is a better solution for this”_ - what’s _wrong_ with implementing this with a simple loop? _“because we can assume the time interval is coordinate on the x axis”_ - how would whatever you assume these values to mean change anything about the basic logic for an overlapping intervals-check?

Comment: @Alive to Die I cannot upload picture for this question . 07:00-10:00 intersect with $time[0] because '08:00-09:00' in 07:00-10:00 , intersect with $time[1] in 09:20-10:00 . just like line segment on a x axis .